# Rollback db operations spanning across separate db sessions, when one of the operations fail

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, commit, rollback

I need to call a db procedure 3 times. All 3 calls will be in 3 different db sessions. 
The requirement is such that if any of the 3 calls fail, all three transactions should roll back. The respective commits should happen only when all 3 procedures have executed successfully.

Already tried solutions:

1. Initiate 3 different connections inside a method. Call the procedure on those connections, and when one of them fails, call rollback on all connections. When the execution of 2nd call failed, rollback was called on 1st connection. This resulted in a SocketException. I do not have the stacktrace available.
2. Using IBM WID and WPS: Encapsulated the db service calls in a single WPS server transaction and made 3 calls to database procedure. This resulted in partial commit, that is, the first call resulted in an insert inside database and did not rollback after the failure of 2nd call.

Comment: If you can instantiate the connections within one method, why do you need three transactions instead of one?

Comment: Its a restriction. The problem that I have to address is to have separate db sessions and coordinate the rollback.